# Why does the terminal search the working directory for files that an executing file is searching for?

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pygame

If the title isn't clear enough the directory has Developer/Pythonfiles/Pong has Pong.py and hit.wav in it.
When i run `~ $python Developer/Pythonfiles/Pong/Pong.py`
The sound hit.wav won't play, A weird popping noise plays instead.
But when I run `~/Developer/Pythonfiles/Pong $python Pong.py` the sound from hit.wav plays as expected.

Why doesn't the program Pong.py search the directory its in rather than my working directory for Hit.wav? I try to access hit.wav with `hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("hit.wav")` and play it with `hit.play()`

Comment: Post your code, and you can get answers not based on guesses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it has no way of automagically knowing that's what you wanted.  So specify the desired behaviour yourself:

```
import os
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "hit.wav"))
```